# Problem accessing a file even with broadFileSystemAccess enabled

Tags: c#, uwp, filesystems, access-denied

I have a UWP Desktop application that has text and audio files associated, for example when the user selects the Class1.txt file, the application automatically tries to open the Class1.mp3 file.
Even with broadFileSystemAccess configured, the operation always returns an access denied error.
Any help is most welcome. Thanks.

```
private async void nviOpen_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

    StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var txtStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
            {
                var encoding = FileEncoding.DetectFileEncoding(txtStream);
                txtStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                var stmReader = new StreamReader(txtStream, encoding);
                var txtContent = await stmReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                tbxOriginalText.Text = txtContent;
            }

            //Open associated audio file
            var audioFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Path + @"\" + file.DisplayName + ".mp3");

            if (audioFile != null)
            {
                MediaPlaybackItem mediaPlaybackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(audioFile));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog msgDlg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
            await msgDlg.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the file system privacy setting and make sure that you've allowed your app for accessing your file system.

Like this:

[image]